# Navigation controller navigationItems doesn't show up as i expected

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I follow a video from youtube. And i ran into a problem when ı try to set Navigation Controller items.

```
    func setupNavigationBarItems()  {
        let twitterImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "twitter_icon"))
        twitterImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        twitterImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        navigationController?.navigationItem.titleView = twitterImage
        
        let profileButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        profileButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "profile_image"), for: .normal)
        profileButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profileButton)
    }
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4JRz.png)

This is the result. Nothing show up

Edit--
I made same changes

```
  navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profileButton)
```

--

```
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profileButton)
```

it just shows the profileButton and button stretches all over to the edges

[new result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnPqs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Click on debug view

[image]

will help you to debug what going on with your view
(Build Project first and you will see this button)

Comment: it can be a lot of reason e.g. ur navigationController is nil or about navBar item constrain

Comment: I did what you told me there is no view in there. But I deleted navigationController?. in my code now it just shows the profileButton and button stretches all over to the edges